# Digital Ocean Space Cors with private files

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean, cors

I am unsure whether I am misunderstanding CORS or whether this is possible within a Digital Ocean Space.

Basically, I want to set a file to private on the DO Space. I only want a certain domain to be able to access this file, so I setup a CORS rule. Can I then access this file over the CDN link from my domain or do I have to do it through the Space SDK.

Thank you